# Understanding if statement within loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm working through some examples from Treehouse via the Python course, and I'm having a hard time understanding the code below.

As far as I can tell we are looping through `"You got this!"`. However, I'm not sure what the `if` statement is actually doing; can someone explain this to me?

```
for letter in "You got this!":
    if letter in "oh":
        print(letter)
```

Comment: this is not a good learning source if the example is only this. you should just `print(letter)` without the `if` to see what happens

Comment: What does it output? Try changing the strings and see how that changes the output

Comment: `letter` is going to be something like `"Y"`, `"o"`, `"u"`, and so on. Do the checks `"Y" in "oh"` and `"o" in "oh"` make more sense?

Comment: I didn't know you could compare a single character by using if letter in "oh" I assumed you that would match oh and not o || h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for letter in "You got this!":

Will loop through every letter in the string:

first iteration: Y
second iteration: o
third iteration: u ....you get how this works
```

During each loop (or iteration), if the letter is either an 'o' or an 'h', it will print that letter.

Comment: Thanks that's a great explanation - I didn't know you could compare a single character by combining them in the if statement I assumed you would have to break it apart using an || statement

Answer (score 0):

So it runs through each letter in "you got this" and if the letter is "o" or "h" it prints it. I ran the code in my IDE and this is the conclusion I came to. My code printed `o o h`

Answer (score 0):

First, you are iterating each character in the string `"You got this!"`, that is the purpose of the for loop. This is something that you have clear, as you have stated.

Second, in this case, the `if` statement basically is saying:

> If the current `letter` is in the string `"oh"` execute the following indented line.

Therefore, the statement `print(letter)` will be executed if the value of `letter` at the current iteration is either `"o"` or `"h"`.

Answer (score 0):

`letter in "oh"` is really just a (IMHO misleading) shorthand for `letter in ['o', 'h']`

Answer (score 0):

The comment are the explanations:

```
for letter in "You got this!": # Iterating trough `"You got this!"` (so 1st time `'Y'` 2nd time `'o'` 3rd time `'u'` ans so on...)
    if letter in "oh": # checking if the letter is `'o'` or `'h'`, if it is, print it, other wise go to the next one
        print(letter) # printing it
```

So that's why the output of this is:

```
o
o
h
```

See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm